# How to automatically encode a text with xslt using external xml data

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a simple xml text and a small personography. I'd like to find all 'people' mentioned in the text and mark them up using information in the personography.
My text looks like this:

```
<text>
    <div>
        <p>Mohandas Ghandi was an Indian lawyer, born in 1869.</p>
        <p>Albert Einstein was a German physicist, born in 1879.</p>
        <p>Helen Keller was an American author, born in 1880.</p>
        <p>Joan Baez is an American singer/songwriter, born in 1941.</p>
    </div>
</text>
```

and my personography looks like this:

```
<people>
    <person id="ghandi">
        <name>Mohandas Ghandi</name>
        <birthPlace>Porbandar, India</birthPlace>
    </person>
    <person id="einstein">
        <name>Albert Einstein</name>
        <birthPlace>Ulm, Germany</birthPlace>
    </person>
    <person id="keller">
        <name>Helen Keller</name>
        <birthPlace>Tuscumbia, USA</birthPlace>
    </person>
</people>
```

So far, I have this xslt (2.0):

```
<xsl:variable name="personography" select="doc('people.xml')"/>   
<xsl:variable name="pName" select="$personography//person[1]/name"/>
<xsl:variable name="pId" select="$personography//person[1]/@id"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>    

<xsl:template name="encNames" match="text()">
    <xsl:analyze-string select="."  regex="{$pName}">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <persName corresp="{concat('people.xml#',$pId)}">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </persName>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
        <xsl:non-matching-substring>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>
```

and I'm getting this back:

```
<text>
    <div>
        <p><persName corresp="people.xml#ghandi">Mohandas Ghandi</persName> was an Indian lawyer, born in 1869.</p>
        <p>Albert Einstein was a German physicist, born in 1879.</p>
        <p>Helen Keller was an American author, born in 1880.</p>
        <p>Joan Baez is an American singer/songwriter, born in 1941.</p>
    </div>
</text>
```

So, my question is, how do I mark up the rest of the people in my text? I assume it will require a function that uses following-sibling, but I haven't gotten much further than that. What am I missing?  Am I at least on the right track?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a little verbose and could probably be optimized or refactored, but works.

This template will iterate through each of the people and apply the analyze-string. The results are in a variable called `$person-matches` with a `<match>` for each person.

If there is a match that contains a `<persName>`, then use that one. Otherwise, use the original text matched in the template.

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:variable name="txt" select="."/>

    <xsl:variable name="person-matches">
      <xsl:for-each select="$personography/person">
        <xsl:variable name="person" select="."/>
          <match>
            <xsl:analyze-string select="$txt"  regex="({$person/name})">
                <xsl:matching-substring>
                    <persName corresp="{concat('people.xml#',$person/@id)}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/>
                    </persName>
                </xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:non-matching-substring>
            </xsl:analyze-string>
          </match>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$person-matches/match[persName]">
            <xsl:sequence select="$person-matches/match[persName]/node()"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>

</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks Mads. I had to do a bit of tweaking, but I got it working to my satisfaction. I give you the win because of performance - on my much larger 'real texts' this performed at nearly twice the speed of Daniel's. Sorry I couldn't upvote - I haven't been around long enough.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is change `pName` to return a sequence of names instead of the name of the first person. I'd then use that sequence to construct a new regex.

Example...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:preserve-space elements="p"/>

    <xsl:variable name="personography" select="doc('people.xml')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="pName" select="$personography/*/person/name"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template match="text()" priority="1">
        <xsl:analyze-string select="."  regex="({string-join($pName,'|')})">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <persName corresp="{concat('people.xml#',$personography/*/person[name=current()]/@id)}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </persName>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for an elegant solution Daniel. The only reason I didn't choose it is because of performance (see comment to Mads). Although it works perfectly on the small sample I provided, the string-join really eats up memory when working on much larger collections.

Comment: @Greg - Performance is a very good reason to choose the other solution. I'm surprised the string-join was the bottleneck though. Was it a much larger "personography", input XML, or both?

Comment: To be honest I don't **know** that the string-join is a bottleneck. Your solution took ~38 sec. while Mads' solution took ~21 sec. (I ran it in oXygen using Saxon-PE 9.5).
The input XML file was ~3MB and there are about 300 people in the personography - eventually this will need to scale to ~2000 people.
I really like your solution, though - it's short and elegant, and for smaller tasks the difference in completion time is inconsequential.
Thanks again!